# AVG values together but only values that have unique IDs

Tags: mongodb

```
{
    "sessionId": 1,
    "sessionDepth": 1,
    "referrer": "espn.com"

},
{
    "sessionId": 1,
    "sessionDepth": 2,
    "referrer": "espn.com"
},
{
    "sessionId": 2,
    "sessionDepth": 1,
    "referrer": "rotoworld.com"

},
{
    "sessionId": 2,
    "sessionDepth": 2,
    "referrer": "rotoworld.com"
},
{
    "sessionId": 3,
    "sessionDepth": 1,
    "referrer": "rotoworld.com"
}
```

**Edit:** the first object should have had a sessionDepth of 1; it was originally at 2; it is now correct.

I want to return the average session depth by `referrer` from the example documents above through aggregation.

The resulting output for the example would be:

```
{
    "referrer": "espn.com",
    "avgSessionDepth": 2,
},
{
    "referrer": "rotoworld.com",
    "avgSessionDepth": 1.5,
}
```

I essentially need to find the session duration by `sessionId`, then average the sessions together by referrer, then add it to a new column.

I tried to do something like this:

Add the totalSessionLength to a new field:

```
 {
                $group: {
                    _id: "$sessionId",
                    totalSessionLength: { $sum: 1 },
                    tmp: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
                }
            },
            {
                $unwind: "$tmp"
            },
            {
                $replaceRoot: {
                    newRoot: {
                        $mergeObjects: [
                            "$tmp",
                            { totalSessionLength: "$totalSessionLength" },
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
```

And then I group by referrer, but I couldn't figure out a way to average only the unique session Ids

```
avgSessionDepth: { $avg: {$cond: Only average unique session IDs}},
```

But I couldn't find a way to only average unique values together

Comment: @whoami thanks for following up. there are still issues. if you look at the mongodb-playground that you sent, the two referrer's are still separate, and in the example above they are combined, because i need the average session length for the specific referrer

Comment: Ok updated my answer & you can try this : https://mongoplayground.net/p/BUcidLQvg22

Comment: The average session depth of rotoworld is not correct; it should be 1.5. This is the flow of the process that i want to achieve: https://imgur.com/a/6c497e8 I have the original data, i find out what the sessionDepth of each individual session is, and then i average those totals by referrer. Also, the sessionDepth for the first object should be 1; i just changed it in the example above.

Comment: @whoami so pretty much this: https://mongoplayground.net/p/hql1imV2lBv Do you know if there's a better way to do it?

Comment: Ok finally it's clear, I've shorten your query to get the same result, Check this (https://mongoplayground.net/p/UsLoeh_KQBv), Let me know if it works I'll make it as an answer with added desc. !!

Comment: let me try to explain differently; each sessionId is the Id for the unique session; each of these records are unique pageviews; sessionDepth is the current page of the session that a user is on; on line four in your mongo playground, sessionDepth should be 1, not 2; when you make that change the output is incorrect.

Comment: Ok there is no big change in it, I've been doing this for `sessionDepth` instead of `sessionId`, try this :: (https://mongoplayground.net/p/VZ2lT-IJTdv)

Comment: It works! Thanks for the help! If you edit your answer and add an explanation, I'll be happy to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below aggregation query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   /** Group on 'referrer', count no.of docs for each  & push unique `sessionId's` to an array */
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$referrer",
      differentSessions: { $addToSet: "$sessionId" },
      sessionLength: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  /** divide total docs per 'referrer' by unique sessions to get avg */
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      referrer: "$_id",
      avgSessionLength: { $divide: [ "$sessionLength", { $size: "$differentSessions" } ] }
    }
  }
])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VZ2lT-IJTdv)